# Amazon EC2 Windows Server 2008 + “Instance Status Checks failed”

Tags: ip, windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2

I have Windows Server 2008 launched on Amazon EC2 Instance.

While doing some configuration I changed IP address to the private IP address of Amazon EC2 instance.

As soon as I changed IP address, remote connection to the instance got disconnected and after that when I tried to reconnect, I am getting the "Instance Status Checks failed" error.

Can any one help me, how can I get into the instance?

Thanks